# How to securely share private docker repo login credentials in Azure container service with Mesos & Marathon

Tags: azure, docker, mesos, marathon, dcos

I have setup Azure Container Service using DC/OS + Marathon for deploying Docker containers. So far looks good, I can connect to master node using SSH tunnel and access Mesos and Marathon WebUI as well as hit REST API.

Next, I am trying to deploy a docker container from my private docker repository and I found following article on Marathon website.

https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker-private-registry.html

Please see the "Note" section from above URL -

**Note**: The URI must be accessible by all nodes that may start your application. Approaches may include distributing the file to the local filesystem of all nodes, for example via RSYNC/SCP, or storing it on a shared network drive, for example Amazon S3. It is worth considering the security implications of your chosen approach.

What options does Azure provides for sharing the docker.tar.gz file across all nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Put your `docker.tar.gz` to Azure Storage and create a signed url. I have used Azure Storage Explorer to create one.

Output;

https://xyzds.file.core.windows.net/docker/docker.tar.gz?...url-params

You need to add file extension in order to marathon extract it.

`x=.tar.gz`

`"uris": [
    "https://xyzds.file.core.windows.net/docker/docker.tar.gz?...url-params&x=.tar.gz"
  ]`

You are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

the way we did it is use `parallel-scp` to push the file to all our mesos agents, something like:

```
parallel-scp -h ~/pssh_all_ips ./docker.tar.gz /etc/docker.tar.gz
```

Where `pssh_all_ips` is a newline separated file of internal IP addresses (`10.0.*.*` or `10.32.*.*` in our case).

You can find your agent IPs at `localhost:2000/mesos/#/slaves` if you're tunneled into your cluster).

This makes the file available at `file:///etc/docker.tar.gz` on all agents, from there you can use marathon's URI field to make it available to the docker pull system.

Comment: thanks for the info. If we know all agents IP then yes this approach would work. But number of slaves would vary as Azure scales them up/down. I am trying to do a deployment using Jenkin by calling Marathon API. I am not sure if this approach is practical to query all agents IP address first. I am hoping Azure Container Service will provide something similar to AWS ECS where using IAM roles we can share file from S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a script to walk the agents in your cluster. Take a look at https://github.com/rgardler/acs-cli for some experiments in doing this.

Comment: Thanks Ross. If there is no other Azure provided way then we will have to use this option. I understand that Azure Container Service is relatively new. I am not sure if this forum is appropriate but may I ask you about Microsoft's long term plan for solving this problem? Or do you think this issue belongs to Mesos/Marathon?

Comment: This forum is appropriate. Our (Microsoft's) plan is to resolve this. I don't have a date to share but something will come along, regardless of whether we decide it's a DC/OS (Mesos/Marathon) or ACS thing, we are contributors to the upstream projects so you can expect us to fix it if no one else does.

Comment: Thanks Ross, will look forward to the fix.

Comment: Is there an update on this? Can I somehow automatically mount a drive/ run a script that mounts an Azure Storage drive on every node (new nodes as well on creation)?

Comment: No date yet, but yes the work is in progress. The above linked CLI tool has examples of how to mount Azure File Storage shares on each node. Blob storage is coming.